# How to emulate Beagleboard on Windows using Qemu

Tags: windows, qemu, emulation

I´m trying to emulate Beagleboard on Windows. Last realeased images can be found here: http://beagleboard.org/latest-images

Anyone know how to emulate it ?

Comment: check this for ubuntu https://wiki.linaro.org/Resources/HowTo/Qemu-beagleboard

Comment: Thanks vinay, yes, I see that article and I try with same parameters and others and can't found the combination to run the image.

Comment: R u trying on windows.? if you are trying on linux then share what combination u tried?

Comment: I´m trying in Windows

Comment: Then u need to get windows compitable binaries for that to work

Answer (score 1):

This is nearly 10 years old but if anyone else was searching for a solution, Qemu now has windows support.  According to the website, Stefan Weil is producing experimental binaries, or Qemu can be installed with Msys2.

https://www.qemu.org/download/#windows